# Searching for an alternative to CPU-Z Validator

Tags: gratis, forum

I'm searching for a software that will periodically upload my hard/software specs/stats from Windows and Android to a webserver so i can embed them as image on forums etc..

http://valid.x86.fr by CPU-Z does the job, but only for hardware, i'm more interested in OS etc..

Comment: Which specific software statistics are you interested in? Which OS, Price Range, etc?

Comment: Thanks. I've integrated the additional details you provided with your question (note that you can always [edit] your posts), and will cleanup comments now. Good luck then!